# Talend - Get all files (in several directories) from FTP

Tags: ftp, talend, getfiles

There are many FTP components to extract files. What should I use if I have a root Directory, with some sub-directories and several files in all of them, and I want to extract all files?

For example:

```
rootDirectory
      - file1.txt
      - file2.txt
      - file3.txt
      - subDirectory1
            - file4.txt
            - file5.txt
      - subDirectory2
            - file6.txt
            - subDirectory2
                  - file7.txt
                  - file8.txt
```

How can I get files 1 to 8, just by giving the component the path to the rootDirectory?

Comment: What FTP client are you using? Is the structure fixed per your description or is that structure just an example? Can you use Perl on your client?

Comment: I'm using FTP components from Talend (or the FTPGet, or the FileFetch)... I want to know what is the right for this case. The directories structure can be different, but I know what folders may exist. Yes, I can use Perl.

Comment: I guess I am saying to make sure the receiving subdirectories exist on your local machine before trying to GET into them.

Comment: The tFTPGet component does what I want, but I was having problems in my FTP connection, and that's why I was getting some errors when I used that component.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used the FTP components yet but typically you'd use a `tFileList` connected to a `tFileCopy` to move files around. So in your case I would expect you should use a `tFTPFileList` connected to your FTP server with a filemask of `"*.txt"` and then connect that to a `tFTPGET`. Set this component to the local directory of your choice, a remote directory of `"/"` and then use `((String)globalMap.get("tFTPFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))` in your Filemask.

This approach seems to be the one I've just found now in the [Talend documentation](https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=13811696#Raa67462) although it might require logging in (free account sign up and probably worth doing if you're using Talend much at all).

It's probably equally fair to say that unless you're planning on doing something complicated with the data rather than just grabbing it most FTP tools should comfortably be able to GET everything from an FTP server and Talend might not be the best approach here.

Comment: That approach fails when I try to go into a sub-directory... It gives me an error because it is not a file...

Comment: @user2144555 Do you have a public FTP server with subdirectories and text files on it?

Comment: Just some friendly advice... if you do a "GET /somedir/somefile" you better make sure that "/somedir" also exists on your local machine!!!! You can avoid this need by adding a different location on the local machine like this "GET /somedir/somefile  newnane" (without a directory).